# Xcode displaying error in fine code

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5

I have declared one constant file in xcode in which i have declared

```
#define MyAppDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

and then using MyAppDelegate whenever it require. 
Now here I am getting error that MyAppDelegate is not declared but when I run this app. it is running fine and also showing me error of that.

```
#import "SearchResultViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "SearchResultCell.h"

@interface SearchResultViewController ()

@end

 @implementation SearchResultViewController
 @synthesize tempArray;
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIBarButtonItem *btnHelp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Help" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnHelpAction:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btnHelp;
self.title = @"Search Result";
tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempArray=[MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray mutableCopy];   // showing me error
;//
```

}

Comment: Ok, where do you import `AppDelegate` which your macro refers to?

Comment: im my Constant.h file.... but it was working fine and i added one functionality to my file and then suddenly i am getting this erro...but if i run with this error it is working fine

Comment: Where do you import `Constant.h`? I don't see it in this listing.

Comment: it works find because the class `AppDelegate` exists in your program, however the compiler is complaining because it can't see the definition within the code you listed.

Comment: so what am i supposed to do here?

Comment: i import constant.h file and all error  gone...but still i cant understand that it was working fine before importing constant.h in previous code...In that I have used MyAppDelegate but at that time it was not giving me an error

Comment: @vivek: Why are you allocating an `NSMutableArray` and then immediately overwriting it with the `mutableCopy`? If you aren't using ARC, that's a memory leak, and even if you are using ARC, it's unnecessary.

Comment: @dreamlax: then instead of that if i will write tempArray=[MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray mutableCopy]; only it will work same???

Comment: yes, you assign `tempArray` to a new mutable array, then on the next line assign `tempArray` to a mutable copy of `MyAppDelegate.searchResultArray`.

Comment: ok so i will write only next line not first

Answer (score 0):

You need to import header file.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create it as an instance variable like

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
tempArray=[appDelegate.searchResultArray mutableCopy];
```

Dont forget to import **YourAppDelegate.h**

```
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"
```